# Problems with SQLite and PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sqlite

I've recently started working with PHP and SQLite and I'm having problems with PHP arrays (I think). This is the code I use:

```
<?php
$dbo = new SQLiteDatabase("rsc/db.sqlite");
$test = $dbo->arrayQuery("DROP TABLE users;");
$test = $dbo->arrayQuery("CREATE TABLE \"users\"(name text, avatar text);");
$test = $dbo->arrayQuery("INSERT INTO users(name, avatar) VALUES('zad0xsis', 'http://zad0xsis.net/');");

// get number of rows changed
$changes = $dbo->changes();
echo "<br />Rows changed:  $changes<br />";

// Get and show inputted data
$tableArray = $dbo->arrayQuery("SELECT * FROM users;");
echo "Table Contents\n";
echo "<pre>\n";
print_r($tableArray);
echo "\n</pre>";

?>
```

And when showing the data (`print_r($tableArray);`) I get this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => zad0xsis
            [name] => zad0xsis
            [1] => http://zad0xsis.net/
            [avatar] => http://zad0xsis.net/
        )

)
```

I don't know why the values are duplicated, like [0] and [name], but it shows the data. Now, when I try to do `print_r($tableArray["name"]);` I should get the value, but it doesn't prints anything :( What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: echo $tableArray[0]["name"]; perhaps

Comment: Try printing like thisc `echo $tableArray[0]['name'];`
`

Comment: you get value duplicate because you're using mysql_fetch_array statement like, try mysql_fetch_assoc for single value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it helps you to select both

```
$tableArray[0]
```

or

```
$tableArray['name'];
```

it's fine.

to your problem: You'll have to

`print_r($tableArray[0]['name'])`

or

`print_r($tableArray[0][0])`

Comment: I'll accept the answer in 7 minutes, when StackOverflow allows me ;)